# Highlight 2nd Instance duplicates in sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to mark duplicates on google sheets, but I see that First Instance is highlighted when I use

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100, A1)>1.
```

I tried to use IF and COUNTIF together so that the 2nd Instance gets highlighted.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A97,A1)>1, "Duplicate", " ")
```

but did not work.

I am trying to use this so that the cell gets highlighted as soon as I enter the duplicate number in the column.

Answer (score 4):

To **`Highlight 2nd Instance duplicates in sheets`** with COUNTIF select ColumnA and: Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... *Custom formula is* and apply:

```
=and(countif(A$1:A,A1)>1,countif(A$1:A1,A1)>1)
```

with highlighting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Should format not *only* the second instance but all other than the first.

Answer (score -2):

you need to lock it with **`$`**

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A, A1)>1
```

[image]

### update:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A, A1)=2
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! That is really helpful. Is there a way to highlight only the second instance ?

Comment: @Sneha answer updated