# I would like a 1 to be added to a box in google sheets if the text on the same line in column B is unique

Tags: google-sheets

I would like a 1 to be added to a box in google sheets if the text on the same line in column B is unique. On those that are not unique, I would like a 1 to be entered on only one of them. Is this possible?
I don't want to manually update this.

Example of the desired result:

[image: This is an example of how i would like it to be]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in cell C1 and drag down / autofill to all the rows:

```
=IF(and(countif(B$1:B,B1)>1,countif(B$1:B1,B1)>1),"",1)
```

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Highlight Duplicates in Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356726/highlight-2nd-instance-duplicates-in-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as an array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A3:A<>"",if(countifs(A3:A,A3:A,row(A3:A),"<"&row(A3:A))=0,1,),))
```

[image]